# Understanding the Event-Loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, events, event-loop

I've been reading a lot about the Event Loop, and I understand the abstraction provided whereby I can make an I/O request (let's use fs.readFile(foo.txt)) and just pass in a callback that will be executed once a particular event indicates completion of the file reading is fired.

However, what I do not understand is where the function that is doing the work of actually reading the file is being executed. Javascript is single-threaded, but there are two things happening at once: the execution of my node.js file and of some program/function actually reading data from the hard drive. Where does this second function take place in relation to node?

Answer (score 1):

The Node event loop is truly single threaded. When we start up a program with Node, a single instance of the event loop is created and placed into one thread.

However for some standard library function calls, the node C++ side and libuv decide to do expensive calculations outside of the event loop entirely. So they will not block the main loop or event loop. Instead they make use of something called a **thread pool** that thread pool is a series of (by default) four threads that can be used for running computationally intensive tasks. There are ONLY FOUR things that use this thread pool - DNS lookup, fs, crypto and zlib. Everything else execute in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

"Of course, on the backend, there are threads and processes for DB access and process execution. However, these are not explicitly exposed to your code, so you can’t worry about them other than by knowing that I/O interactions e.g. with the database, or with other processes will be asynchronous from the perspective of each request since the results from those threads are returned via the event loop to your code. Compared to the Apache model, there are a lot less threads and thread overhead, since threads aren’t needed for each connection; just when you absolutely positively must have something else running in parallel and even then the management is handled by Node.js." via http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Answer (score -2):

Its like using, `setTimeout(function(){/*file reading code here*/},1000);`. JavaScript can run multiple things side by side like, having three `setInterval(function(){/*code to execute*/},1000);`. So in a way, JavaScript is multi-threading. And for actually reading from/or writing to the hard drive, in NodeJS, if you use:

```
var child=require("child_process");
function put_text(file,text){
  child.exec("echo "+text+">"+file);
}
function get_text(file){
//JQuery code for getting file contents here (i think)
return JQueryResults;
}
```

These can also be used for reading and writing to/from the hard drive using NodeJS.

Comment: javascript is sequential - it handles external processes with callbacks - in your example of timeout an api is used with passing a callbackpointer, once fullfilled it goes on queue. - child_process is node - also an api use by javascript - "side by side, is multi-threading" - just (sounds) wrong